# g++ "does not name a type" error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, makefile, g++, header-files

I'm working on a little project for my structures class and have run into an issue even the TA couldn't figure out. It was suggested that I post about it on here and I might get some help. So here it goes:

**Overview:**
I'm using g++ to compile a project containing a number of header (.h) files along with their corresponding implementation (.cpp) files. The project involves 3 separate structures and running a timing comparison between them. The structures being implemented and compared are a binary min heap, a leftist heap, and a skew heap. The min heap implementation is complete and is compiling just fine. However now that I'm moving onto the other structures I'm running into what I assume (I know) is a compiler error.

**The Issue**
I'm fleshing out the stub files for the leftist heap and have hit a brick wall as far as the compiler is concerned. In particular I'm getting an error that reads:

```
leftHeap.cpp:15:1: error: ‘LeftistHeap’ does not name a type
```

**The Code**
Here's a look at relevant code:

leftHeap.h

```
#ifdef LEFTHEAP_H
#define LEFTHEAP_H

class LeftistHeap{

 public:
  int *root;
  LeftistHeap();
  ~LeftistHeap();
};

#endif
```

leftHeap.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "leftHeap.h"
using namespace std;

//Constuctor
LeftistHeap::LeftistHeap(){

 root = NULL;
}
```

The only other place that leftHeap.h is included is in the main.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "minHeap.h"
#include "leftHeap.h"
#include "skewHeap.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){
...
```

here's the makefile I'm using:

makefile

```
all: lab10

lab10: comparison.o minHeap.o leftHeap.o skewHeap.o
        g++ comparison.o minHeap.o leftHeap.o skewHeap.o -o lab10

comparison.o: comparison.cpp
    g++ -c comparison.cpp

minHeap.o: minHeap.h minHeap.cpp
    g++ -c minHeap.h minHeap.cpp

leftHeap.o: leftHeap.h leftHeap.cpp
    g++ -c leftHeap.h leftHeap.cpp

skewHeap.o: skewHeap.h skewHeap.cpp
    g++ -c skewHeap.h skewHeap.cpp

clean:
    rm lab10 *.o
```

and just to be extra thorough I've also tried a more minimalist makefile

makefile (2)

```
test:
    g++ minHeap.h leftHeap.h skewHeap.h comparison.cpp minHeap.cpp leftHeap.cpp skewHeap.cpp -o lab10
clean:
        rm lab10 *.o
```

I hope that's not info overload. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas on this. I've looked at the other g++ "does not name a type" issues on here (and a couple of full page of google searches as well) but haven't found anything that may account for this. I have this sneaking suspicion that it may be something simple I've overlooked but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your include guard really carefully: `#ifdef LEFTHEAP_H`.

Comment: Fantastic! I knew it was something simple... It took far longer to make that post than to fix the problem but it's done! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a typo (assuming it is transcribed accurately):

```
#ifdef LEFTHEAP_H
#define LEFTHEAP_H
```

in leftHeap.h should be #ifndef

```
#ifndef LEFTHEAP_H
#define LEFTHEAP_H
```

Comment: That was it! Wow you guys are fast, I'm going to have to start posting (and stop lurking) more often.